# @IBAction recursive call

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uialertaction

I just would like to get a second opinion on if there's any unforeseen issue with calling IBAction functions recursively. I am asking this question because of a crash that happened once and I found it hard to replicate.

Let say we have this call:

```
var allowedToSend = false

@IBAction func emailButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {

  if !allowedToSend {

    let controller = UIAlertController(title: title,
                    message: "Are you sure you want to send the Email?",
                    preferredStyle: .Alert) 

     controller.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes please, send.", style: .Default, handler: {
                    action in

                    self.allowedToSend = true; 
                    self.emailButtonPressed(sender) // call self again
            }))  

     controller.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Default, handler: nil))
     presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
     return // exit the function

  }

  // Reset the value
  allowedToSend = false

  // Sending code

  let text = textArea.text
  let to = toLabel.text

    ....    

}
```

Is this the right way to call an `@IBAction` recursively in Swift?

Comment: Does this not just make a UIAlertController over and over again?

Comment: What are you trying to do? You removed too much of the surrounding code for it to be possible to say if you are doing something wrong.

Comment: `IBAction` is the same method as any other. There's no difference at all, `IBAction` is just a hint for xcode. Your problem is definitely somewhere else.

Comment: Sorry guys, I added more code

Comment: You can do it like that I guess, but why not just put the sending code in the action block?

Comment: @dan I am doing this only for a specific case where the user is about to commit a mass sending to all the contacts in his address book. Therefore, I am reminding her, that she's going to do that before sending.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is the correct way to call the function recursively like you would with any other function.

Note:
It is not a good habit to create this many UIControllers, regardless of their type. 
Also, since your recursion is not designed to end, this will lead to an infinite number of calls and probably cause the program to crash from a stack overflow - I would not recommend that.